# Where and How are the legendary characters during Rime of the Frostmaiden?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms, rime-of-the-frostmaiden

I'm DMing ROTF for players that have a very deep knowledge of the lore of the Forgotten Realms, it doesn't bother me at all, but I would like at least to be prepared enough anyway to properly address the campaign theme. I've read "The Crystal Shard", and keep digging into wiki and other sources of lore, but there is still a lot of things that I don't know for sure.

Worth noting that we known at least "when" it happens, as the book says:

> This adventure is assumed to take place in the winter of 1489 DR or later. The exact date is not important. The happenings in this book occur more than a century after the events chronicled in R.A. Salvatore’s novel The Crystal Shard, which introduced the drow hero Drizzt Do’Urden to the hardy folk of Icewind Dale.

Massive spoiler for the Forgotten Realms books or some other campaign books.

About Bruenor, Catti-Brie & Regis:

> Bruenor is dead, but does anyone knows he is reincarnated as Reginald Roundshield? Does he himself? Same for Catti-brie and Regis?

About Drizzt:

> From what I understand Drizzt is trapped in another plan? There is nothing about him left in Icewind Dale, except maybe legends from old nannies?

About the Dwarf, and more specifically the Battlehammer clan?

> Is Connerad Brawnanvil still The leader of the Battlehammer clan? It's unclear from Rise of Tiamat.

Overall do you have any advice on how to proceed with lore accuracy in the campaign, and some sources of lore I could read in preparation

Comment: See this question for a date reference for the adventure's setting: [What is the year in Dale Reckoning for Rime of the Frostmaiden?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/175653)

Comment: Yes indeed, the "when" is not really part of the question as being answered in the campaign book itself (and I've already seen your mention question).

Comment: Right, but it's a helpful reference point for users looking to nail down the time period this question concerns.

Comment: Very related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133756/where-are-the-heroes-of-faer%c3%bbn-during-tyranny-of-dragons-according-to-other-adve/133775#133775

Comment: Remember that unless your players are meta gaming, it doesn't matter what they know.   There is no reason for their characters to ask about those legendary figures in the first place.

Comment: 100% agreed @SamLacrumb, I just known hey will love to have a bit of meta context on the campaign itself, and it'll be great for immersion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relentless goes up to 1488, just before the events of Rime of the Frostmaiden. As such, we aren't entirely sure what everyone is up to.

That said, Bruenor, Cattie-brie, and Regis has long since been reincarnated and reunited. Drizzt was in Icewind Dale as recently as 5 years previously, so I think his memory will be still strongly alive!

In Archmage Connerad is killed, the remaining dwarves in Icewind Dale are lead by  Stokely Silverstream as of at least 1484.